# Playmarket does not show app update

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-market-filtering

I have some strange problem with my app.

I create a new version of my app with minor update, also was updated some libraries so I get changes in permissions with only location permissions

**Bad version**

```
android.hardware.BLUETOOTH
android.hardware.FAKETOUCH
android.hardware.LOCATION
android.hardware.MICROPHONE
```

**Good version**

```
android.hardware.BLUETOOTH
android.hardware.FAKETOUCH
android.hardware.LOCATION
android.hardware.location.NETWORK
android.hardware.MICROPHONE
```

So I got problem what users who have installed good version can't see updates in market.

For example devices Samsung S4 mini, S7 Edge

Also I can simulate problem by these steps:
1. Install good version from APK
2. In market see only Delete and Open, but not update.

Good version - version code 1

Bad version - version code 2

How to fix? Or what problem is it?

Comment: AFAIK you can't update 3rd party APK's through Google Play.

Comment: what is that code from? That doesn't look like permissions

Comment: Reaper, ok thank you for information. And how detect second problem, user have good version from market, and after I upload bad version, he did not see it at market?

Comment: Vlad, it's not code from manifest, it's copy past from developer console.

Answer (score 0):

These IDs are not permissions but features, which are also displayed in the Play Console. They may be explicitely [declared in the manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) or deduced by the Play Store from the permissions.

If you declare an api level >= 21 and a location permission, you have to declare [that you use the corresponding feature](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Permission) :

> Caution: If your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher, you
>   **must** declare that your app uses the `android.hardware.location.network` or `android.hardware.location.gps`
>   hardware feature in the manifest file, depending on whether your app
>   receives location updates from `NETWORK_PROVIDER` or from `GPS_PROVIDER`.
>   If your app receives location information from either of these
>   location provider sources, you need to declare that the app uses these
>   hardware features in your app manifest.

What happens if you explicitly add the `android.hardware.location.NETWORK` or `android.hardware.location.gps` feature to the manifest ? or if you lower the target level to 19 ?